# mysql database not stopping after killing PID

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have my node server to run on port `3306` and whenever I try to run it their is a process running on the same port. After running the command `lsof -t -i :3306` I can see that mysql is running. I then run the command `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown` and it says that `mysql` has shutdown successfully. I then try to run my node server but I keep getting the errr `Address in use`. I check again and see the `mysqld` process running. I keep killing but it doesn't stop. How can I kill it and stop from coming back?

Comment: There's probably a service to stop. Something like `/etc/init.d/mysql stop` or the like. Restarting will probably bring it back, too. Why on *earth* would you want to run a Node app on 3306, though? That's just asking for trouble (like this!).

Comment: I am using a mac so i dont see `/etc/init.d/`

Comment: Then consult https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100948/how-do-you-stop-mysql-on-a-mac-os-install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

- Stop the MySQL service in Windows Task Manager(ctrl + alt+del then services) or on Services.msc (windows key + r , then type services.msc)
- uninstall MySQL in the computer (if you don't need it anymore)
- as user @ceejayoz said, make your node.js app/webserver listen to a different port so you don't have to do the above. If you're using Express.js port 3000 is good [if you don't need elevated privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37929243/2155668)

Comment: I have my react application listening on 3000 and node listening on 3306.

Comment: How about 8000?

Comment: @moeeli Or pretty much any port not already on the list in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers. 3001, 3002, 3003 are all open for use. 3005-3019, 3021-3049, etc. etc. etc. Picking a commonly used one (and one that'll commonly be used by a Node app) is a little insane. :-D